# Kivy TextInput to be above Android keyboard, however rest of screen to stay where it is

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am building a quiz game in Kivy, that has a TextInput option for users at the bottom of the screen. It's at the bottom because the clues for the answers are displayed at the top.

The issue I am having is when I deploy my app to my phone, the Android on-screen keyboard pops up and blocks out nearly half my screen.

I tried the `softinput_mode` in the Windows package, but this seems to push my entire screen up and so now, the top half of the screen is gone (and users can no longer see the clues).

Is there a way to incorporate this within the FloatLayout where my TextInput box is?

If it helps, here is a sample code that will help you recreate the issue and see what I mean:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"

class TestBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class RVTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestBox()


RVTestApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<GameWindow>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.5)
            font_size: 80
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            text: "TEXT AT TOP OF SCREEN"
        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.05}
            size_hint: (0.3, 0.05)
            id: guess
            multline:False
        Button:
            text: "CHECK BUTTON FOR ANSWERS AT BOTTOM OF SCREEN"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "y": 0.05}
            size_hint: (0.3, 0.05)
```

Would really appreciate any help on how to get this bit fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue Erik Sandberg's YouTube channel:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.softinput_mode = "target_bellow"
```

Just write that anywhere in in your code and it will work.

Comment: In addition to "bellow" being misspelled, that's inconsistent with [Kivy's own documentation for `softinput_mode`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.softinput_mode), which specifies `below_target` (as noted in [@Nuzhin Ivan's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774816/3025856)). Further, the _only_ reference I can find to `target_bellow` on Google is your answer on this thread. Are you ***certain*** you meant `target_bellow`? If so, what's your source for that information?

Answer (score 0):

It's bellow target according to kivy doc meaning Sandberg he just made mistake

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).