# Why is it when I use the same layout for two classes, one layout doesn't show up?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to test the difference of having the kivy.Windows package inside a class vs outside a class (to try and solve the issue I am having here: [Kivy TextInput to be above Android keyboard, however rest of screen to stay where it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396416/kivy-textinput-to-be-above-android-keyboard-however-rest-of-screen-to-stay-wher) ).

I am therefore trying to see if I have two separate FloatLayouts, within two classes, can I control just one of them. However what I noticed is that if I include both FloatLayouts within the same class, it displays everything fine, but if I try and have them in two separate classes, the top one vanishes, and no matter how I change the position, I can't see it on my screen. Why is this happening?

Here is my .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

#Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"

class Header(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestBox(FloatLayout):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("rec_view.kv")

class RVTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestBox()
        #return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RVTestApp().run()
```

Here is my .kv file:

```
<Header>:
   FloatLayout:
      Label:
         pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, "top": 0.1}
         size_hint: (0.2, 0.5)
         font_size: 40
         text: "TEXT AT TOP OF SCREEN"
<TestBox>:
   FloatLayout:
      TextInput:
         pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.05}
         size_hint: (0.3, 0.05)
         multline:False
      Button:
         text: "CHECK BUTTON FOR ANSWERS AT BOTTOM OF SCREEN"
         pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "y": 0.05}
         size_hint: (0.3, 0.05)
```

I thought it was initially because I was returning TestBox(), but even if I return Header() or kv, it shows a blank.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and there was no issue returning the `TestBox()`, however, the `Header()` didn't display anything.
This was primarily due to the `pos_hint` `top` being set to `0.1` instead of `1`.

Both the functions are working now

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

#Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
string = '''
<Header>:
   FloatLayout:
      Label:
         pos_hint: {"top": 1,'center_x':0.5}
         size_hint: (0.2, 0.5)
         font_size: 40
         text: "TEXT AT TOP OF SCREEN"

<TestBox>:
   FloatLayout:
      TextInput:
         pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.05}
         size_hint: (0.3, 0.05)
         multline:False
      Button:
         text: "CHECK BUTTON FOR ANSWERS AT BOTTOM OF SCREEN"
         pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "y": 0.05}
         size_hint: (0.3, 0.05)
    '''
class Header(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestBox(FloatLayout):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_string(string)

class RVTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestBox()
        #return Header()

        #return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RVTestApp().run()
```